# How can I place a white image at the top and bottom (eg: 40px) of every image in an html file in js?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, dom

I am trying to add an image/blank rectangle on top of/overlaid on the top and bottom of every image on an html page. I plan to do this via a user-script, but I could not find any information on how to append an image on another at a specified PX x PX. I am slightly familiar with js. I have done two small hobby projects (an image parser and a poker game) this being the third, and assume I will have to achieve following:

1. Create a blank image to cover the top and bottom part of the image.

   This can be done by creating a simple rectangle I think. I can play with the parameters of the size to make it fit.
2. get every image on the site

   I can probably do this by parsing the `DOM` (I'm not sure if I need to do this if I am using a user-script) and doing a `forEach(img)`, and within the `forEach(img =>` I can add the rectangle to the top and bottom thereby adding it to every image on the page.
3. somehow append the blank image from above on top of the top and bottom of each image.

   This is where I am lost. I have appended images to the DOM before, but I don't know how to do it through a user-script and I also don't know have to append an image on another image. I have thought of doing the following, but I am unsure how to continue:

I also have linked an example where I would use this user-script. What I am trying to do is remove a watermark. (I am only doing this locally on my computer as to not steal the translators work, which is why I am using JavaScript.) So to recap I am looking for how to solve number 3, and if possible/optionally an explanation of how to do this in grease-monkey or any other user-script manager. Let me know if anything was unclear and thanks to anybody who comments/answers this problem. edit:clarity

[here is a link to an example use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHgRz.jpg)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you are going to be able to achieve the goal your wanting to with just JavaScript alone. Well thats not 100% true, you may be able to achieve something in canvas. You may require some back end processes, passing the image to a server, letting it run imagemagik on it or similar library. Unless your talking about layering something over an image, and not physically modifying the images.

Comment: @chris yes I am talking about just layering the image. I thought about re-encoding it but I don't what to steal the work by altering the watermark, i just don't want to see the watermark when I'm reading. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need these two balnk space on each img on the page, just using this css:

```
     img{
           height: 945px;
           object-fit:cover;
     }
```

Or js:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.height = "954px";
     x[i].style.objectFit = "cover";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the js answer in grease monkey (a user-script manager) and it didn't seem to work.. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for that, i just edit my script. Please use that!

Comment: The updated js does do something now but it seems to move the images away from each other rather than crop them. Is this wrong?

Comment: please i need your confirm on what exacly you want: you want to add 40px space at the top and bottom of every img on you page right? or you need to crop them?

Comment: What I meant was I want to replace the bottom and top with the white image or crop them. So in the end part of the original image should not be seen. Sorry I was not clear in my original post.

Comment: js could not be actually crop the img. But we can use js set the css for those imgs to hide parts of them. But it's will be a mess if your imgs very different in size. if tthey are the same size - i will give you some codes for that!

Comment: yes! all the images are the same size. i would appreciate that.

Comment: so what exactly size of the display part of those imgs you want (the display - not the hide part!)?

Comment: here is the link https://manhuaplus.com/manga/rebirth-of-the-urban-immortal-cultivator/chapter-345/. The pictures are 800x1131. I don't know how much to take off.. maybe 40px vertically?

Comment: please to hear that. But i recommen you to use the css if you can. This will make your site faster and avoid unwanted conflict later than the js one!